# Apex Change Set equivalent to release.config/debug.config

Tags: apex, deployment

We have a constant URL string pointing to a staging webservice.  When deploying change sets to Production, we would like this constant URL to change to the production webservice.  Is there a way for a change set to automatically do this transformation during deployment?  (Basically, the way it works publishing debug/release versions in .Net.)

Alternatively, I can create a class called Constants containing Production constants, and deploy it once, then modify it to contains staging constants in my sandbox during development.  I was just wondering if there is another more automated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run code automatically after a changeset deployment, unless you use `ant` or something similar to do the deployment.

However, what you can do is change your code ever so slightly and handle logic differently whether you're in Sandbox or not. For example

```
Boolean isSandbox = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
String myString = (isSandbox) ? 'ToSandbox' : 'ToProduction';
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised Salesforce doesn't have something like a constants table for dev/prod.  In the meantime, thanks, that's exactly what I needed.